# Analytic properties of motivic L-functions twisted by Dirichlet characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, motives, functional-equations

Let $M$ be a pure motive over $\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the (completed) $L$-function $\Lambda(M, s)$ attached to its $\ell$-adic realization. Let us assume that this $L$-function admits analytic continuation and a functional equation relating $\Lambda(M, s)$ and $\Lambda(M^\vee, 1-s)$ as conjectured. Let $\chi$ denote a quadratic Dirichlet character.

Can one deduce the analytic continuation and functional equation of the twisted $L$-function $\Lambda(M, \chi, s)$ from the properties of $L(M, s)$?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No, except for $GL_2$ motives of level 1 (Hecke's theorem) and maybe some other very special examples.

Comment: In $\mathrm{GL}_2$ there is Booker's Theorem https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2003/158-3/p11

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Thanks for Brooker's paper, I was unaware of this result.  @WillSawin I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge but which Hecke's theorem are you referring to? I guess another example would be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, since then both $M$ and its twist are modular, but it is perhaps wrong to say that the analytic properties of one is deduced from the other...

Comment: Searching "Hecke's converse theorem" should bring all the information (on that theorem) you need.